# Is there an alternative to `apply --prune` in `server-side` mode?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to manage my cluster objects declaratively and I'm having problems automatically deleting objects whose resources' files were removed.
I know there is the `apply --prune` option but that doesn't work without the `last-applied-configuration` annotation ([here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#:%7E:text=and%20it%20has%20a%20last%2Dapplied%2Dconfiguration%20annotation%2C%20it%20is%20deleted.)),  and because I'm working in SSA(`server-side`) mode this annotation is omitted.
So I was wondering what's the best way to, declaratively, automatically delete objects from my cluster?